# How to send FCM Multiple notification message to different topics at once

Tags: php, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I checked many answers, they all about sending notification to different topics, but I want to send different messages to different topics at once.

I have 100+ topics to send notification, sending one by one takes too much time to send.

I didn't find any API documentation so I try different techniques, like $fields send multi dimension array, but it returns an error.

My code is only sending 1 notification at once.

How can I send all messages in a single request?

```php
 // Sending through PHP Curl request
 $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

 $msgs = array();
 $msgs["topic_1"] = array("title"=>"title 1","body"=>"topic 1 message");
 $msgs["topic_2"] = array("title"=>"title 2","body"=>"topic 2 message");
 $msgs["topic_3"] = array("title"=>"title 3","body"=>"topic 3 message");
 ...
 $msgs["topic_100"] = array("title"=>"title 100","body"=>"topic 100 message");


 foreach ($msgs as $topic => $message) {
    $fields = array(
         'to' => "/topics/$topic",
         "priority"=> "high",
         'data' => $message,
         "time_to_live" => 7200
    );

    $headers = array('Authorization:key=API_KEY',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);           
    curl_close($ch);
 } // loop end

 //above code only send 1 message at once..
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#build_send_requests)

You can send notification to multiple topic by use **condition** parameter in your massage

For example, the following condition will send messages to devices that are subscribed to TopicA and either TopicB or TopicC:

> "'TopicA' in topics && ('TopicB' in topics || 'TopicC' in topics)"

Full example :

```js
// Define a condition which will send to devices which are subscribed
// to either the Google stock or the tech industry topics.
var condition = "'stock-GOOG' in topics || 'industry-tech' in topics";

// See documentation on defining a message payload.
var message = {
  notification: {
    title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.'
  },
  condition: condition
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the combination of topics
// specified by the provided condition.
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

> NOTE : You can include up to **five** topics in your conditional
>   expression.